# How to perform a context menu action on a file using python 3

Tags: python, automation, contextmenu, pywinauto

How can i do a context menu action on a particular file?
I managed to open the explorer and get the list of files through python using pywinauto.

On that file I need to perform a context menu action, is it possible through pywinauto?

```
import pywinauto

path = "C:\\Users\\Vishnu\\Desktop\\DM-test\\"

pywinauto.Application().Start(r'explorer.exe')
explorer = pywinauto.Application().Connect(path='explorer.exe')
NewWindow = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True,  class_name='CabinetWClass')
NewWindow.AddressBandRoot.ClickInput()
NewWindow.TypeKeys(path+'{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
```

The code above will open the explorer and navigate to the dir. This is the Context menu action required on the file:
[image: this is the Context menu action required on the file]

I managed to find the reg value and changed my code to pass that action to the file, It works perfect!!

`pywinauto.Application().start(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\QCAT 6.x\Bin\QCAT.exe" -txt "{}"'.format(fileName))`

Comment: Why not just read out the desired action from the Registry and execute it on the file directly? This seems like a long way around to do something very basic...

Comment: What's wrong with `explorer.exe` example in the main Readme? [scroll to the middle of page](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto#ms-ui-automation-example)

Comment: @zwer Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to find the reg value and changed my code to pass that action to the file, It works perfect!!

`pywinauto.Application().start(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\QCAT 6.x\Bin\QCAT.exe" -txt "{}"'.format(i))`

Comment: Do you think you could share your full code on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrgh! Nobody reads the docs... The example is provided in the main Readme: [MS UI Automation Example](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto#ms-ui-automation-example). For your case it should look like that:

```
# no need to type the path, explorer.exe has a cmd param for that
pywinauto.Application().start(r'explorer.exe "{}"'.format(path))

# backend is important!!!
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="explorer.exe")
NewWindow = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True,  class_name='CabinetWClass')

file_item = NewWindow.ItemsView.get_item('dmlog20180517-121505slot0.dlf')
file_item.right_click_input()
app.ContextMenu["Convert to QCAT Text"].invoke()

# further actions depend on a process / dialog started...
```

More details about backends: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: Hey Vasily, I'm currently using this similar method but facing a problem of clicking the sub menu part of context menu.  For example, `app.ContextMenu["Convert to QCAT Text->Sub Menu Item"].invoke()`. Do you know of a way I could go about?

Comment: I've posted my question here as well -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997575/pywinauto-how-to-click-select-sub-menu-of-context-menu)